# Moodle auth plugin - Call to undefined function

Tags: php, moodle

I'm trying to create my own moodle authentication plugin (/moodle/auth/manualspace/auth.php).

Inside it I want to call a function, but during execution an error message is displayed.

Can someone give a light?

Message error:

> Exceção - Call to undefined function exibe_msg()

Code:

```
public function exibe_msg() {
   echo "
   <html>
   <title>Problem</title>
   <body>
   <h1>You're not allowed...</h2>
   </body>
   </html>";
}

function user_authenticated_hook($user, $username, $password)  {
    global $CFG;

    exibe_msg();

    require_logout();   

   exit(0);

}
```

Thanks in advance

Roberto

Comment: is this in a class right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: If this code runs at all, it means that the function is actually **not** in the file as you show, because `public function` throws a syntax error when not in a class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Can you Show us the whole class ?

It must Look Like this https://github.com/catalyst/moodle-auth_basic/blob/master/auth.php

and then the function call must look like this :

```
$this->exibe_msg();
```

Answer (score 0):

`public function` means it is inside class and not abstract, so you have to instantiate your class first